# Why are files copied to mounted folder from inside the container not appearing in the host folder?

Tags: windows, docker, neo4j, docker-compose

When I mount a host folder to my neo4j container the files from in that folder appear inside the containers directory and things work. However files that are inside the containers directory do not appear in the corresponding host folder - like the config file inside the container, located in the mounted conf folder.

```
version: "3"
services:
  cneo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.3.5
    container_name: cneo
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=db.localhost.vm
      - VIRUAL_ENABLE_SSL=True
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=db.localhost.vm
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@example.com
      - CERT_NAME=db.localhost.vm
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/moeter/cmcr/data/graph_main/neo4j/data:/data:rw
      - /c/Users/moeter/cmcr/data/graph_main/neo4j/logs:/logs:rw
      - /c/Users/moeter/cmcr/data/graph_main/neo4j/conf:/conf:rw
    restart: always
```

I am using Docker Toolbox for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A host volume will always map to the contents of the host directory, there is no merging of contents from the image or initialization of the host directory from the image. The process of populating the host directory has to be done by your container entrypoint or command. If there's initial data you want to load, that will need to be saved elsewhere in the image since you cannot access the image folder contents of they are hidden under a volume mount.

Comment: ok, however, when i go to the folder inside the running container the files from the mounted host directory and those that come from the image are there. In the host directory on the host I only see the files from the host, that have been there initially.

Comment: @haemse What happens if you change one of the files on the host? Sounds like you may not be mounting the volume you expected. Include the output of a `docker inspect` on the container id in your question.